# STM32 20 pin cable pinout

Tags: stm32, connector, jtag, pinout

I have an STM32 20 pin cable used by the ST-Link to programme the microcontrollers like the one in the image

[image]

I know the pinout of the connector is the one below

[image]

unfortunately I can't find the connection between the pinout of the connector with the one of the cable. I know the red wire is the VDD and the pin 1 but the others? Are they consecutives? like the second wire from the red one is the pin2, the third the 3 etc?

Comment: This would be the JTAG 20 pin interface. It's not unique to STM32, although Cortex M tend to use a subset of it called SWD, using an 1.27mm 2x5 connector instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wires in cable are in increasing consecutive order 1,2,3,4 etc.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, the cable itself is just 1,2,3 and so on from the red strip=1.

IDC socket connectors like these pretty much always have triangle symbol in the plastic, acting as arrow, pointing at pin 1. You'll find it on either side of the red strip, quite likely at the same side as the notch.

From there it's enumerated like any double row socket/header strip (picture taken from datasheet of [Samtec TCSD, IDC socket cable assembly](https://www.samtec.com/products/tcsd)):

[image]

(Though as you can see from this, reverse wiring is apparently an option)